# Which version of Hahn-Banach is this proof using?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I am referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem

Which version of Hahn-Banach Theorem is the proof using?

As I am aware, there are different versions of Hahn-Banach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem), e.g. geometric Hahn Banach, etc, however I am not sure which version this proof is using.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See the second point of "important consequences" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Important_consequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\phi \colon U + \def\span{\operatorname{span}}\span\{x\} \to \mathbf R$ by 
$$ \phi(u + \lambda x) = \lambda \def\d{\operatorname{dist}}\d(x,U) $$
Then $\phi$ is bounded, as 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
  \abs{\phi(u+\lambda x)} = \abs{\lambda} \abs{\d(x,U)} \le 
\abs{\lambda} \norm{x - (-\lambda^{-1}u)} = \norm{u+\lambda x} $$
Hence $\norm{\phi} \le 1$. By Hahn-Banach (the extension version) there is an $\Phi \in X^*$ such that $\norm{\Phi} = \norm{\phi} \le 1$ and $\Phi|_{U+\span \{x\}} = \phi$, that is $\Phi|_U = 0$ and $\Phi(x) = \d(x,U) \ge 1+\delta$.

Comment: How do we conclude $\|\phi\|=1$? I can only see $\|\phi\|\leq 1$. Thanks,

Comment: You are right, will correct.

Comment: I think we can "normalise" $x$ to be $\|x\|=dist(x,U)$, then use $\|\Phi\|=\sup_{\|y\|=1}|\Phi(y)|\geq|\Phi(x\text{dist}(x,U)^{-1})=1$ to prove the other inequality?